# Pass multiple domains to restrict - in "hd" parameter in Google OAuth

Tags: google-oauth, google-account

I'm using Google OAuth for account linking.

I'm setting `hd` parameter to restrict particular domains ([Ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param)), and it's working fine.

but my question is can I restrict more than one domains?

like currently I'm setting `hd` as

```
"hd": "jaypatel.co.in"
```

> **But what if I want to allow two or three domains instead of just**
>   **`jaypatel.co.in`? is there any way to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

I know that I arrive a bit late but I tried to pass different domains as an Array

`hd: ['mydomain1.com', 'mydomain2.com']`

and it seems to be the behavior you looked for.

Comment: Do you know what this serialises to in the actual URL that you redirect to?

Comment: @MarkEmbling Sorry, it's been a while so I don't remember right now

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't seem to work. The array is serialized as a string, like `['mydomain1.com', 'mydomain2.com']` and it doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just from setting the `hd` parameter, no this behavior cannot be accomplished. If you try to set multiple, you'll get an error like this:

> OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: hd

If you want to *optimize* for multiple domains, another option is to set the value of the `hd` parameter to `*`. [The docs for that parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#hd-param) point out:

> To optimize for Google Cloud organization accounts generally instead of just one Google Cloud organization domain, set a value of an asterisk (*): hd=*.

**Note:** From what I've seen with this approach, it does allow the user to pick their account still, but once they've selected an account to log in with for the first time, it will continue to select that account. This may or may not be what you're trying to accomplish.

You'll still have to implement logic to validate the returned token to ensure that it belongs to one of the domains you've specified, though. The docs have more details on that [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#validatinganidtoken).